# template specialization -> 'too few template-parameter-lists'

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, template-specialization

i can't find what's wrong with this code:

```
template <class T>
class B{
    T _t;
public:
    B(T t) : _t(t) {}
    void printHello();
};

template <class T>
void B<T>::printHello(){
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
void B<char*>::printHello(){
    std::cout <<"Good bye!";
}
```

I keep getting:

> 'error: too few template-parameter-lists'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`template<>` is missing before the specialization

```
template<>
void B<char*>::printHello(){
    std::cout <<"Good bye!";
}
```

Comment: <code> #include <iostream>

template <class T>
class B{
    T _t;
public:
    B(T t) : _t(t) {}
    void printHello();
};

template <class T>
void B<T>::printHello(){
    std::cout << "Hello";
}

void B<char*>::printHello(){
    std::cout <<"Good bye!";
}

int main(){
 B<double> b(5);
 b.printHello();

 char* str = "iko";
 B<char*> c(str);
 c.printHello();
}






</code>

Comment: I don't get any such error with `template<>` added. Which version of g++ are you using?

Comment: oh... sorry... my bad... i restart eclipse and now it works... thanks!